# HTTPS connection rejected on Amazon ec2 instance

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-ec2, https, apache2

I have updated inbound rule to accept HTTPS, but when I hit from browser I get error err_connection_refused. I have run netstat -nupt -l but it does not show HTTPS opened. Is there any other way I can open https

Answer (score 0):

You have to check two things to ensure that the HTTPS port are really opened in EC2.

1. [Iptables](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/01/iptables-fundamentals/). Ensure that the 443 port is opened to your desired IP
2. [EC2 Security Groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html). Go to the EC2 Managment console, go to "Network and Security" and find at witch security group is attached your machine. You can see the attached SG (security group in the instance properties). Probably it's not opened 443 port.